I want to use a function to capture the value of each code on each button on my simple calculator project
I did a calculator project that has numerous buttons using the onclick event to assign codes to each button, I want to use a function to avoid repeating codes on each button, help please
I tried using a function but have no idea on how to capture the value of each button as it ranges from 1-9 and also operators -,+,*,/, eval
